# Problem with GAE, HTTP/3 and custom domain

Tags: google-app-engine, http3

I have a site votebd2.appspot.com which is normally accessed by its custom domain votebd.org. It connects via http/3 when accessed via the appspot URL but not via votebd.org. This doesn't make sense to me - anybody know how to fix this?